# How to filter in many to many relation

Tags: django, many-to-many

I want to get all Post which are realated whith tags:

```
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('blogUserPlane.Tag')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


#views.py
def get_list_of_posts_by_tag_order_by_date(request):
    # this works
    list_of_posts = Post.objects.all().filter(tags__in=[1, 2])
    # I want to use tags as name, not as id. Samething like this
    # list_of_posts = Post.objects.all().filter(tags__in=["Tag1", "Tag2"])
    html = ["title=%s<br> tags=%s<br>" % (p.title, p.tags.__dict__) for p in
```

list_of_posts]
        return HttpResponse(html)

The second problem is that filter return wrong result:

```
Post:
| id | title | 
|  1 | post1 | 
|  2 | post2 |

tags:
| id | post_id | tag_id |
|  1 |    1    |    1   |
|  2 |    1    |    2   |
|  3 |    2    |    2   |

Tag:
| id | name | 
|  1 | Tag1 |
|  2 | Tag2 |
```

list_of_posts = Post.objects.all().filter(tags__in=[1,2]) returns:
post1, post1, post2, but should return post1, post2

Comment: What is blogUserPlane?

Comment: It is name of app in django, for this question it is not important, important is that there is model class Tag

Comment: To filter posts by tag names just change it to Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=['name1', 'name2'])